# meteor logginbutons how to disable sign-up

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor's logginButtons in my app.

I would like to remove the ability to sign-up.

Isn't there a config I could edit to do that?

I could tweak the css but it is not very clean...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Accounts.config](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_config)

Both Client and Server need this:

```
Accounts.config({
    forbidClientAccountCreation: true
});
```

Comment: This will indeed prohibe the creation of new users, server side but in my views, the "create button", "Sign-up" text, etc. are still present. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Got it! I had put it on the server instead of putting it on the client... Thanks!

Comment: @ndemoreau you need it on both

Comment: I added config folder in root/lib/ and moved accounts.js into this folder. Is this the right way to go?